# Balanced Binary Search Tree with Backtrcking

Tags: algorithm, backtracking

I want to write the algorithm of Balanced Binary Search Tree with backtracking would you please guild me about it? I dont know how should I implement it. I dont want any code I need just explanation.

Comment: You mean a balanced binary search tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a self-balancing binary tree. I recommend [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree)s or [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)s, which are both pretty straightforward.

There are other binary tree extensions with similar strengths (and possibly easier implementations), so check out the related links at the bottom of those wikipedia articles.

Comment: I agree that a red-black or AVL tree is probably the best solution but I think it's misleading to call them "straightforward."

Comment: @finnw: I never said they were easy. They're straightforward though, because you can implement them directly as specified in the article. Ie you don't have to invent anything new.